# TYPO3 (7.6.14) Extbase TCA: Field missing in mask after setting foreign_sortby

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

After I set the **'foreign_sortby' => 'datum'**; this field is missing now at my edit mask. Does anybody know why?

TCA of tx_veranstaltungen_domain_model_terminblock (1 terminblock can have multiple termine)

```
    'termine' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:veranstaltungen/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_veranstaltungen_domain_model_terminblock.termine',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'inline',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_veranstaltungen_domain_model_termin',
            'foreign_field' => 'terminblock',
            'foreign_sortby' => 'datum',
            'maxitems' => 9999,
            'appearance' => array(
                'collapseAll' => 0,
                'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
                'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                'useSortable' => 1,
                'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
            ),
        ),

    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found it out whats the problem, after reading [Bug report](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/27659)

You should use foreign_default_sortby instead of foreign_sortby, because IRRE hides the field you use for sorting. The **dangerous** thing is, that the field could be overwritten by "sorting values". So I wondered why all my fields (of type date (timestamp)) has the value 01.01.1970... because the field values changed to 1,2,....

I hope this can help others, before they destroy their data. :)

(I'm using Typo3 7.6.14)